# Buttons get deselected due to a click event anywhere on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have made a `Bill Splitter` which basically calculates the tip and the total amount each person has to pay on a bill. It has multiple button to select the tip percentage. These buttons are deselected when the user clicks anywhere on the webpage. **But I want that the buttons be deselected only when the user clicks on any other button.** Please correct my code.

**CODE :**

```js
let bill_amount = document.getElementById("amount");
let humans = document.getElementById("people");
let tip_buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tip"));
let reset_button = document.getElementById("reset");
let custom_tip_button = document.getElementById("custom");
let tip_percentage, tip_person, total_bill_person;
let bill_amountFilled = false;
let humansFilled = false;
let buttonClicked = false;

tip_buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    tip_percentage = parseFloat(button.innerHTML);
    buttonClicked = true;
    calculateTip();
});
});

custom_tip_button.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    tip_percentage = parseFloat(event.target.value);
    buttonClicked = true;
    calculateTip();
});

function calculateTip() {
  if (bill_amountFilled && humansFilled && buttonClicked) {
    tip_person = (parseFloat(bill_amount.value) * (0.01 * parseFloat(tip_percentage))) / parseFloat(humans.value);
    total_bill_person = parseFloat(bill_amount.value) / parseFloat(humans.value) + tip_person;
    document.getElementById("tipPerPerson").value = tip_person.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("totalPerPerson").value = total_bill_person.toFixed(2);
  }
}

bill_amount.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  if (bill_amount.value.trim() !== "") {
    bill_amountFilled = true;
    calculateTip();
  } else {
    bill_amountFilled = false;
  }
});

humans.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  if (humans.value.trim() !== "") {
    humansFilled = true;
    calculateTip();
  } else {
    humansFilled = false;
  }
});

reset_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    location.reload();
});
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
    font-family: "Space Mono";
}

h4 {
    color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    margin: 5% 50% 0% 45%;
}

h5 {
    font-size: small;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

h6 {
    margin: 3%;
    color: hsl(185, 22%, 45%);
}

.line2 {
    margin-top: 0%;
}

.calculator {
    display: flex;
    margin: 4% 15% 0% 20%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2.5%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0.9%;
}

.left-box {
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-input {
    background-color: hsl(189, 41%, 97%);
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    width: 80%;
}

.left-input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid aquamarine;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}

#custom {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: hsl(189, 41%, 97%);
    color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    width: 25%;
    height: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    border: none;
}

.btn:focus {
    background-color: hsl(166, 61%, 39%);
}

.custom:focus {
    background-color: hsl(161, 28%, 62%);
    color: #fff;
}

.right-box {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    padding: 2.5%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.right-input {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: hsl(161, 42%, 58%);
    text-align: right;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.btn-lg {
    background-color: hsl(161, 42%, 58%);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    h4 {
        margin: 5% 30% 5% 40%;
    }

    .calculator {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    .left-box {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }

    .right-box {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Tip Calculator App</title>
  <!--Font Awesome Links-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd6cc398e6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap Links-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--CSS Links-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="top-heading">
    <h4 class="line1">SPLI</h4>
    <h4 class="line2">TTER</h4>
  </div>

  <main>
    <div class="calculator">
      
      <div class="left-box">
        <h6>Bill</h6>
        <span class="text-addon"><i class="fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="left-input" id="amount">
        <h6>Select Tip %</h6>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary tip">5%</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary tip">10%</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary tip">15%</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary tip">25%</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary tip">50%</button>
        <input type="text" class="left-input" id="custom" placeholder="Custom">
        <h6>Number of People</h6>
        <span class="people-addon"><i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="left-input" id="people">
      </div>

      <div class="right-box">
        <h5>Tip Amount / person</h5>
        <input type="text" id="tipPerPerson" class="right-input" readonly placeholder="$0.00"><br><br><br>
        <h5>Total / person</h5>
        <input type="text" id="totalPerPerson" class="right-input" style="margin-left: 40px;" readonly placeholder="$0.00"><br><br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using the `contains` function to check whether any click event is inside the tip buttons or not, but I couldn't do it successfully. Being a beginner to JavaScript I am not able to think of any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Defeating native behavior common to all browsers is bad. A natural way in your use-case would be to use radio buttons instead of buttons. You can always style the button to look like active when it's clicked, only that you've to store the clicked to button in a variable, and restore its style when another button is clicked.

Comment: The buttons are not selected in the first place. Due to focus CSS it looks like they are selected but they are not. Nothing to do with outside click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the focus function of CSS as that would change colour upon clicking elsewhere. You can do what you want by adding an event listener in JS to add a class to the button when it's clicked, and then remove that class when another button is clicked. I've used 'active' here in this simple example:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.my-button');

function removeActiveClass() {
  buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'));
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeActiveClass();
    button.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.my-button.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="my-button">Click me!</button>
  <button class="my-button">Or click me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

This would ensure that buttons do not lose focus when you click somewhere else.